# How to remove QTY box from product details page in Magento?

Tags: magento

How can you remove the QTY box from the product details page for configurable products?
Is it possible to remove the QTY box from the shopping cart too?
I am using Magento Community version 1.7

Comment: `Google` is the best place for such type of questions

Comment: Do you always want the customer to add qty=1?

Comment: Please provide more details

Answer (score 4):

If you are using base Magento theme then,
Go to

> base->default->template->catalog->product->view->addtocart.phtml

There you will find the QTY input box. Now you can do whatever you want.
Have a nice day.

> The path is template reference only, you should follow magento coding
>   standard and modify accordingly. Don't change base files. I hope you know about Magento
>   Fallback hierarchy.

Comment: (it's rwd, not base folder that works without extra xml config)

Comment: It would be better to avoid changing file in the base theme. It better copy over the file you have to modify in you current theme.
By the way the template reference is correct. The answer from @Marwen is working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Go to app/design/frontend/your_interface/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Find:

```
 <input name="qty" type="text" class="input-text qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>"/>
```

and replace with:

```
<input type="hidden" disabled="disabled" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product)? $this->getMinimalQty($_product): 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
```